# Name "shape" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, class, if-statement, inheritance, scope

Doing an inheritance test program specifically to root out problems such as these.

The classes themselves aren't important, the problem is in the Main.

I tried "Shape shape = null" before the if statements but having "Circle shape" etc in the if statements threw errors.

Main:

```
    string shapeType = "";
    double side = 0;
    while (true)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("What type of shape? - (cir/tri/sqr");
      shapeType = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("How long are the sides, or the radius?");
      side = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
      if (shapeType == "cir")
      {
        Circle shape = new Circle();
      }
      else if (shapeType == "tri")
      {
        Triangle shape = new Triangle();
      }
      else
      {
        Square shape = new Square();
      }

      // Code interacting with shapes.
    }
```

Comment: Declare Shape shape before the first if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring the shapes within the `if` blocks, which means that after that block ends it's unavailable.

You need to declare it before, and as a `Shape`:

```
Shape shape = null;

if (shapeType == "cir")
{
    shape = new Circle();
}
else if (shapeType == "tri")
{
    shape = new Triangle();
}
else
{
    shape = new Square();
}

// … etc
```

Comment: Ah-ha! It was the class names before the declaration. I tried doing the "Shape shape = null" before but then the if blocks were returning errors about "shape" already existing within the current scope. I didn't know that the "Circle/Triangle/Square" before the cast becomes unnecessary with inheritance.